# Free Generic Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to understand how a generic list works in C. I made the **add** function (that adds nodes at the start of the list) which works pretty good but I got stuck at destroying the list. Something isn't working in **destroy_all_myList** because i get a **segfault**.
I've attached my **add** function because I thought maybe there could be a problem.

```
#include "myList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void add_myList(struct myList **head_list, void *data)
{
    size_t dataSize;
    struct myList *newNode;
    dataSize = sizeof(data);
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct myList));
    newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(dataSize));   
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head_list;
    *head_list = newNode;
}

void destroy_all_myList(struct myList **head_list)
{
    struct myList *newNode;
    while (*head_list)
    {
        newNode = (*head_list)->next;
        free((*head_list)->data);
        free(*head_list);
        *head_list = newNode;
    }
}
```

There is my header file:

```
#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H

struct myList
{
    struct myList *next;
    void *data;
};

void add_myList(struct myList **head_list, void *data);
void destroy_all_myList(struct myList **head_list);

#endif
```

There is my **main** which works if I don't call the destroy function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    struct myList *list = NULL;
    void *data;
    *(int*)data = 5;
    add_myList(&list, data);
    add_myList(&list, data);
    add_myList(&list, data);
    //destroy_all_myList(&list);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You're leaking memory, then saving the address of non-dynamic memory in your handling of the `data` member during addition. The result is later, when you try to free that pointer, your heap manager goes kerboom as you invoke *undefined behavior*. And `*(int*)data = 5;` is utterly wrong on inception in `main()`. `data` is *indeterminate*; more undefined behavior.

Comment: `dataSize = sizeof(data);`  Hmmm - unclear.  Why the size of a `void *`?  `newNode->data = data;` overwrites the previous `newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(dataSize));`

Comment: You are overwriting the pointer you're allocating for new data: `newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(dataSize));` followed by `newNode->data = data;`. You need to *copy* the data passed in to the newly allocated area (or have the caller pass in the actual new data block, which isn't what you're doing). Also, you didn't allocate space for `void *data;` and try to dereference: `*(int*)data = 5`. That's a big problem. Why not just `int data;` then pass `&data` to the `add_myList` (after taking care of the other problem I mentioned)?

Comment: Do you want to add to the list a `void*data`, or a copy of what the calling code's `data` points to?

Comment: I want to add in to the list a certain data type and I was thinking that I need to allocate memory for that data type that is the thing with the sizeof(data). The thing with * (int *)data = 5 was only to test my code. I tried to printf list data and it worked. I thought it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that you're not allocating the right amount of data. You allocate the sizeof(void*) bytes, which is 8 bytes, but that's fine for int, because sizeof(int) is 4 Bytes. What if you need more data? So you should pass the amount of data you need allocate.

I found multiple mistakes in your code, so it would be easier for me to show some code:

I'd also add the content (data) size, you may need it in some cases.

```
typedef struct      s_list
{
    void            *content;
    size_t          content_size;
    struct s_list   *next;
}                   t_list;


t_list              *ft_lstnew(void const *content, size_t content_size);
void                ft_lstdelone(t_list **alst, void (*del)(void*, size_t));
void                ft_lstdel(t_list **alst, void (*del)(void *, size_t));
```

`ft_lstnew()` creates a single 'node' with the given content ([code](https://github.com/TermanEmil/c-linked-list/blob/master/src/ft_lstnew.c)).

`ft_lstdelone()` deletes a single node, where the `del` pointer to function takes care of freeing the content (You may have a structure with multiple allocations, so you must free each allocated structure element, not just the content itself) ([code](https://github.com/TermanEmil/c-linked-list/blob/master/src/ft_lstdelone.c))

`ft_lstdel()` deletes the entire list. ([code](https://github.com/TermanEmil/c-linked-list/blob/master/src/ft_lstdel.c))

`void               ft_lst_push_front(t_list **first, t_list *new);`

this function adds the `new` element at the start of the given list. ([code](https://github.com/TermanEmil/c-linked-list/blob/master/src/ft_lst_push_front.c))

With that setup you can do something like this:

```
typedef struct  s_some_data
{
   char *name;
   char *surname;
}               t_some_data;

...

t_some_data *new_data(char const *name, char const *surname)
{
    static t_some_data result;

    result->name = strdup(name);
    result->surname = strdup(surname);
    return (&result);
}   

...

//No need of the data size in this case
void delete_data(t_some_data *data)
{
    free(data->name);
    free(data->surname);
    free(data);
}

...

t_list    *head = NULL;

ft_lst_push_front(&head, ft_lstnew(new_data("A", "B"), sizeof(t_some_data));
ft_lst_push_front(&head, ft_lstnew(new_data("C", "D"), sizeof(t_some_data));

ft_lstdel(&head, (void (*)(void*, size_t))&delete_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code and now it looks like this:

In **main** I declared **data** as an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    struct myList *list = NULL;
    int data = 5;
    add_myList(&list, &data);
    add_myList(&list, &data);
    add_myList(&list, &data);
    destroy_all_myList(&list);
    return (0);
}
```

In **add** function I deleted the thing with the data size which made no sense and now the **destroy** function works. I checked in valgrind and there seems to be no memory leaks now.

```
#include "myList.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void add_myList(struct myList **head_list, void *data)
{
    struct myList *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct myList));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head_list;
    *head_list = newNode;
}

void destroy_all_myList(struct myList **head_list)
{
    struct myList *newNode;
    while (*head_list)
    {
        newNode = (*head_list)->next;
        free(*head_list);
        *head_list = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I sincerely hope you understand that *all* of your list nodes have `data` members pointing to the *same address* (the address of `data` in `main()`). If that was the intent, so be it. If it wasn't, I'm sure you'll find out soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar problem some time in the past. It uses macros.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/ojmakke/ojlib/blob/master/ojllist/ojllist.h

You can declare a linked list of, say int, by calling the macro:

```
OJLIST(int,0)
```

This allows you to create a linked list, and push to it, and get from it using the functions:

```
ojllistint_create
ojllistint_push
ojllistint_get
```

If you declare it as:

```
OJLIST(struct YourStruct* ,10)
```

Then you get a linked list of array[10] of pointers to YourStruct, and starts behaving automatically like a dynamic array.

I tested it for multithreading and it works. Although it make look complex, it is worth looking at how you may approach such a generic problem.